# Has an architect ever forgotten the weight of the books when designing a library?

Tags: architecture

A common story that is sometimes repeated, going as far to be included in an episode of [How I Met Your Mother](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosbius_Designs), is as follows:

> Once an architect was commissioned to design a library, they put a
>   lot of effort into it and the client was pleased; however, once it was
>   built it started to sink into the ground. Turns out that they forgot
>   to take into account the weight of the books.

The moral of the story being to double check your work and make sure you factor in all variables; however, has this ever actually happened?

Comment: According to [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/college/halls/sinking.asp) (June 2011): `So far, the "weight of the books" explanation has failed to hold up about any library it's been told about (and the list ist endless).`

Comment: I heard a similar story about a building at Birmingham University, in the UK, which was designed by architecture students to have a swimming pool on stilts, but they forgot to take into account the weight of the water...

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down votes?

Comment: @Oliver_C I would think that comment qualifies as an answer. Snopes is generally reliable, and if the story has been told about multiple libraries and none has been shown to be true then we can be pretty confident it's made up.

Comment: As a Civil Engineer I think it's worth noting that Architects don't usually take account of the weight of anything. That is the engineer's job.

Comment: The architect who designed the departmental library at my university forgot about the bookshelves and was very unhappy when they were added as they spoiled the design. There wasn't any floor collapse due to weight issue though, I assume the engineer in charge wasn't as incompetent as the architect. This is only anecdotal stories in the department though, I'll post as an answer if I find any references.

Comment: @Nick - From what others have said and I've found in my own readings, I wouldn't be surprised if this ends up being one of those situations where there isn't anything official documented in wide distribution, but in client or firm files there might be a source or two.

Comment: This actually did happen at a place I worked at; there was a second-floor library on the campus and a couple years after it was built people noticed the ceiling under it was starting to sag. All the books were removed and some work was performed to add some additional support to the ceiling. Don't think the books are being moved back though.

Whether that's because the engineers forgot to take the weight of the books into account or because of some other mistake I can't say, but the book explanation is certainly plausible.

Comment: At Glasgow University in the 1980s, I was spun the same yarn.